# Counting table rows after insertRow

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table as following:

```
<table id="order-summary">
  <caption id="order-summary-title">Order Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th>QUANTITY</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is the JavaScript snippet that inserts new rows into the body dynamically. This snippet is either triggered or looped by some other part in my app in order to add more rows.

```
let orderSummaryTable = document.getElementById('order-summary')
  alert("Current body row count: " + orderSummaryTable.tBodies[0].rows.length)
  newRow = orderSummaryTable.insertRow(orderSummaryTable.tBodies[0].rows.length+1)
  let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = orderItem.name;
  cell2.innerHTML = orderItem.quantity;
  cell3.innerHTML = orderItem.cost.toFixed(2);
```

The problem I am facing is that: the row count always stay `0` even after a new row is successfully inserted. In addition, the intention is to insert the new row at the end of the table (as in the code). But since the row count remains `0`, any new row gets inserted at the top (below the header).
Note that the row is actually inserted,albeit for the issue described above. Why doesn't the table update its row count dynamically? Thanks.

Also, any css style intended to apply to the newly created rows does not take effect. It's like the new rows do not seem to be part of the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the inspector you would have noticed that the line was inserted in the `thead` and not in the `tbody`, using this code instead as you see everything works.

```js
function AddRow(){
   let orderSummaryTable = document.getElementById('order-summary').tBodies[0];
   let lastRowIndex = orderSummaryTable.rows.length;
   let newRow = orderSummaryTable.insertRow(lastRowIndex)
   let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
   let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
   let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
   cell1.innerHTML = 'hello';
   cell2.innerHTML = '3';
   cell3.innerHTML = '10';
   newRow.style.color = 'red';
   console.log("Current body row count: " + orderSummaryTable.rows.length);
 }
```

```html
<table id="order-summary">
  <caption id="order-summary-title">Order Summary</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th>QUANTITY</th>
      <th>TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onClick="AddRow()">Add</button>
```

Comment: You are welcome, i add style and button for create row.

Answer (score 1):

you are not inserting row in the table body

to do that use:

`newRow = orderSummaryTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].insertRow(-1)`

-1 to insert in the end automatically